# Fragments with circle transition using viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, android-viewpager, carousel

In view pager, i have two fragments which contain the image and its name when we swipe the pager there should be a smooth transition. If we are showing the first fragment left right side second fragment to need to be displayed as shade one when we swipe it the second fragment will get focus and the first fragment will display as shade one. I want to implement as the following image.

[image: GIF of implementation require]

[image]

When fragments changing it will show an animation.

I have tried everything in Google, like custom transition and for view pager, carousel imageview

https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/11/making-carousel-layout-in-android.html&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1544587349609000&usg=AFQjCNHEG39jAuuOJBaaS-peyqw5-a6eOg

https://www.google.com/url?q=https://github.com/DevExchanges/AndroidCarouselLayout&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1544587854474000&usg=AFQjCNFi3y5626M_zin7Umng0EayS5507g

Some of the links which I have tried.

I have even try using single fragment still unable to do.

EDIT:- I have attached gif od implementation.

Comment: did you try depth page transition for viewpager

Comment: @JyotiJK i have tried it but not getting the same effect.

Comment: can you share gif or video of transition you want

Comment: @JyotiJK i have attached the gif, please check.

Comment: https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager

Comment: @XarEAhmer I had tried that library but it is not working.